# Do Majorana qubits have a future?

Tags: quantum-computer, majorana-fermions

There are still major efforts to observe Majorana Fermions in condensed matter systems (most recently [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2207.02472)), with the ultimate goal of using topologically protected Majorana qubits for quantum computing. This is Microsoft's main approach right now. Existing observations of Majorana modes have been pretty controversial so far.

But let's suppose they are able to robustly observe all the Majorana physics that they want. To my knowledge, all the proposed ways to make physical Majorana qubits are subject to quasiparticle poisoning; if you break a Cooper pair on the nanowire that you use to host the Majorana, you decoherence your qubit. Naively you would expect to be able to exponentially suppress quasiparticles as you lower the temperature, but in practice long-lived non-equilibrium quasiparticles are a major issue that's not going away. They're a major source of decoherence in superconducting qubits, a competing architecture. In fact, I've heard that the effect of quasiparticles in practice is so strong that people may first attempt to detect the qubit by detecting fluctuations coming from its state changing very rapidly.*

So given the above, is there any proposed way around the quasiparticle issue, or argument for how this problem can be solved? It's hard to understand the point of building a topologically protected qubit if it's not robust to one of the main sources of decoherence in the considered platform (aside from it being very cool physics!)

([Cross-posted in quantum computing Stack exchange](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/31822/do-majorana-qubits-have-a-future), as suggested in comments)

*This was in a talk by Kathryn Moler, who was talking about detecting the resulting telegraph noise with SQUIDs.

Comment: so you expect answers in the form of a big list of proposals?

Comment: Just one proposal in the context of the current nanowire-based platforms would suffice! Or any argument as to why quasiparticle poisoning doesn't make this whole endeavor a non-starter. I edited the last paragraph to make the question more specific.

Comment: All the other quantum computers out there suffer from horrible decoherence issues... so why not one more?